# Python: Lib to use epoll if available, fallback to select

Tags: python, select, python-asyncio, epoll

I would like to use [select.epoll()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.epoll) in my Python library.

Unfortunately epoll is not available everywhere.

I need a way to fallback to [select.select()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.select).

I tried to find something at pypi, but failed to find a matching package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=epoll&submit=search

How could I solve this "fallback from epoll to select if epoll is not available"?

Comment: How about using libevent which wraps all these 

http://libevent.org/

Comment: @AkhilThayyil if you write your comment as answer, then I will upvote it. The libevent thing looks good.

Comment: read before changing to epool: [epoll is fundamentally broken part 1](https://idea.popcount.org/2017-02-20-epoll-is-fundamentally-broken-12/),  [epoll is fundamentally broken part 2](https://idea.popcount.org/2017-03-20-epoll-is-fundamentally-broken-22/)

Comment: @internety thank you for the link to "epoll is fundamentally broken" at the current stage the concerns of this article don't apply to my use of epoll, but nevertheless good to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from `selectors` stdlib, I would go with [uvloop](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/uvloop), which is built on top of `libuv` in Cython. Compare to `libevent`/`libev`, those two do not have actively maintained python binding, uvloop is more promise.

Answer (score 10):

Python 3.4 introduced the [selectors module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html). It offers a `DefaultSelector` that is an alias to the "most efficient implementation available on the current platform".

Here's a quick usage example:

```
sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()

sel.register(fp1, selectors.EVENT_READ)
sel.register(fp2, selectors.EVENT_READ)
sel.register(fp3, selectors.EVENT_READ)

for key, mask in sel.select():
    print(key.fileobj)
```

You can find a more [complete example on the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html#examples).

`DefaultSelector` will try, in this order:

- `epool` (Linux), `kqueue` (FreeBSD / NetBSD / OpenBSD / OS X) or `/dev/poll` (Solaris)
- `poll` (Unix)
- `select`

Answer (score 3):

How about using libevent which wraps all polling mechanisms and falls back to the best available one based on your platform [libevent.org](http://libevent.org)

Comment: http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html is also promising  (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyev/) ..

Comment: does it have an up to date python binding?

Answer (score 3):

Here are my two cents on this. According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.epoll), epoll is available only on Linux 2.5.44 and newer. With code:

```
import os
if os.uname()[0] != 'Linux' or os.uname()[2] < '2.5.44':
    #use select
else:
    #use epoll
```

Better yet, I reckon that the above could be turned into a nice decorator, to be used wherever you want in your program, that returns the correct function depending on the underlying os.